# Where Should I Publish My Artificial Intelligence Paper?

Tags: publications, journals, computer-science, arxiv

I've been working on an AI project in the past two years. And I found some interesting things that I think might be useful for humanity and can enrich the current status of AI.

So, I wrote a paper, made it open source so that others could benefit from it. And I knew some people that submitted their AI papers on `arXiv`, so I tried to do the same but my paper got *rejected*.

I'd like to know where do people usually submit their AI paper. I need a popular platform with good audience; I want my paper to be heard. I obvious can't use `arXiv` and at this point I don't even like to submit my paper there because they don't understand the value of a paper.

(I've heard about viXra, but I think I can do better than that.)

Comment: Unforuntately, if you've gotten rejected from arxiv it means that you will also surely get rejected from any reasonable publication

Comment: @Taw so should I just stop?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. As it stands, there are several issues with your question. Please [edit] it if you can: 1) The only question is in the title and that’s a [shopping question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3657/7734). 2) Your academic background/situation is unclear. Are you affiliated with an academic institution? 3) What do you roughly know about academic publishing in general, i.e., where do we need to start explaining?

Comment: Would you please provide the reason why your paper was rejected by arXiv?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that I'd like to add in order to be able to help you in understanding what you're actually asking.

In accordance with your question: **I'd like to know where do people usually submit their AI paper.**
This is perhaps the authors' preference and needs a background check of the widely available avenues and journals in the area of artificial intelligence. This strongly depends on authors' understanding of the magnitude of their work which is perhaps why it is important to understand where you stand in your research timeline (Independent Researcher, Affiliated to a Research based Company or an academic institution)

Second thing, I'd like to point out what I understood is that you're actually new to research and thereby willing to put your idea out, due to your understanding of it being valuable to the community. It is because, if you had some prior research experience or were slightly aware of several subtleties of research process, you'd know that `arXiv` is a public repository/ a preprint server where early drafts of research ideas are submitted, so that the ideas are put out for public scrutiny and early access to other researchers in the field, (which in your case was the ideal choice since you want your ideas to be **heard**).

There may be several reasons why your paper was rejected from `arXiv`:

1. **Poor writing style with a lot of typos and grammatical mistakes**
2. **High percentage of plagiarism**, etc

With reference to this: **they don't understand the value of a paper**:
Try submitting your paper to a journal in your area but with certain considerations prior to submission of your work.

1. Check whether you've added relevant related literature to help the reviewers understand why your results are valuable
2. Take any journal specific style and format your paper accordingly.
3. Make sure to check the plagiarism of the paper from any good plag software like `turnitin` etc
4. Proofread your paper and improve it (because `arXiv` has very minimalistic requirements for a paper to be accepted than any peer-reviewed journal, like @Taw said, if it is rejected from `arXiv` its highly unlikely that it will be accepted in any journal at all.)
5. Also make sure you check that your references are not messy.

You can also put it out on Elsevier's SSRN (with possible needed modifications to the paper obviously).